# Regular expression to recognize (X, Y, ... and Z) in C#?

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

Given the set of input strings below:

- one, two, and three
- one, two, three, and four
- one, two, three, four and five

(... and so on for the N + 1 cases)

How can can I construct a regular expression that can recognize phrases like this for any number of nouns and return each comma delimited noun and the final noun that follows the *and* conjunction as a separate capture group?  If it is not possible, what approach would you use to parsing and capturing input such as this?  I'm using the C# Regex object for parsing.

**Note, the nouns here are just sample data (one, two, three, four, five, etc.) and the spaces following the commas might be omitted. Also, the nouns might be multi-word phrases separated by spaces**

*Bonus round*: if you can cleanly also recognize the non-comma delimited cases for (example) "one" and "one and two" in the same expression with capturing.

Comment: Does it have to use RegEx? I believe this can be easily done with `string.Split()`.

Comment: Yup. Split, and trim each entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex

`\b((?!and)\w+)\b`

Regex Demo : http://regex101.com/r/kC5rR2

You can also check the result at [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/)

[image]

Comment: Your regex seems to fail on the `nouns might be multi-word phrases separated by spaces` requirement

Comment: @PeterM: Thank for pointing the mistake. I will update it soon :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.  However I can't get ride of the "," in the final match of the form "two, and three"

```
(?<word>\w+,* and \w+)|(?<word>(?<=^|,\s?|and )\w+)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a simple method instead of Regex just to keep the code simple and readable to other developers.

Following code shows you this method in action using a console app. Hope it helps you.

Cheers!

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "one, two, three, four, five, thirty one and six";

            // Get all nouns into a string array
            string [] allNouns = getNouns(input);

            // Print the result
            foreach (string noun in allNouns)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(noun);                
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string[] getNouns(string input)
        {
            string[] nouns = input.Split(',');

            if (input.ToLower().IndexOf("and") > 0 && nouns.Length > 0)
            {
                string[] lastTwoNouns = nouns[nouns.Length - 1].Trim().ToLower().Replace("and", "~").Split('~');

                Array.Resize(ref nouns, nouns.Length + 1);

                nouns[nouns.Length - 2] = lastTwoNouns[0];
                nouns[nouns.Length - 1] = lastTwoNouns[1];
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < nouns.Length; i++)
            {
                nouns[i] = nouns[i].Trim();
            }

            return nouns;
        }
    }
```